# Add a new column to data table

Tags: r

I am working with a data table that contains 5 columns:

```
gene_id, length, sample1_count, sample2_count, sample3_count
```

I want to add 3 new columns to the existing table that is representative of the normalized counts of sample1, sample2 and sample3 (i.e. divide each sample count for each gene by the total number of counts).

How can I create 3 new columns? Or do I need to do this when I first generate the file in unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` way to do this

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("^sample\\d+_count", names(df1), value = TRUE)
setDT(df1)[, paste0("Norm_", nm1) := lapply(.SD, `/`, .N), gene_id, .SDcols = nm1]
```

If it is to divide by the `sum`

```
setDT(df1)[, paste0("Norm_", nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), 
                             gene_id, .SDcols = nm1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful to include a minimum reproducible example, but the following will call a function for dividing a field by the number of cylinders in the `mtcars` dataset, storing the output under new variable names:

```
mtcars
fields_input <- c('hp', 'disp')
fields_output <- c('hp_per_cyl', 'disp_per_cyl')
divide_by_cyl <- function(v) v / mtcars[['cyl']]
mtcars[fields_output] <- lapply(mtcars[fields_input], divide_by_cyl)
mtcars
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some reproducible data:

```
 set.seed(1)
 df <- data.frame(gene_id = 1:5, 
                  length = sample(1:100, 5), 
                  sample1_count = sample(1:10, 5), 
                  sample2_count = sample(1:10, 5), 
                  sample3_count = sample(1:10, 5))
```

This is how to normalise by sample count, rename the normalised columns and finally join the normalised columns to the original data frame (using base R functions):

```
norms <- sapply(df[ c("sample1_count", "sample2_count", "sample3_count")], function(x) x/sum(x))
colnames(norms) <- sub("count", "norm", colnames(norms))
df2 <- cbind(df, norms)
```

And here are the normalised counts:

```
df2[, c("gene_id", "length", "sample1_norm", "sample2_norm", "sample3_norm")]
  gene_id length sample1_norm sample2_norm sample3_norm
1       1     27   0.29032258   0.11538462   0.15151515
2       2     37   0.32258065   0.07692308   0.21212121
3       3     57   0.19354839   0.23076923   0.24242424
4       4     89   0.16129032   0.38461538   0.09090909
5       5     20   0.03225806   0.19230769   0.30303030
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your data could be represented better using long format. With a long format and using `data.table` your problem becomes much simpler:

```
# Some sample data
dt <- data.table(
         gene_id = sample(LETTERS, 10),
         length = sample(1:25, 10),
         sample1 = sample(1:1000, 10),
         sample2 = sample(1:1000, 10),
         sample3 = sample(1:1000, 10))

# Convert to long format
dt_long = melt(dt, id.vars = c("gene_id", "length"), value.name = "count")

# Calculate your normalized counts for each gene_id / length combination
dt_long[, normalized_count := count / sum(count), by = c("gene_id", "length")]
```

If you need your output in wide format again, you could always use:

```
dcast(dt_long, gene_id + length ~ variable)
```

to get:

```
gene_id length   sample1    sample2    sample3
 1:       B     16 0.2666667 0.05232068 0.68101266
 2:       C      6 0.7737226 0.01459854 0.21167883
 3:       J      3 0.4131455 0.41549296 0.17136150
 4:       P     13 0.4846847 0.44054054 0.07477477
 5:       Q     23 0.3425573 0.11545802 0.54198473
 6:       R     12 0.6018576 0.21114551 0.18699690
 7:       S      4 0.5416924 0.30759728 0.15071032
 8:       T     24 0.1838666 0.40694006 0.40919333
 9:       X     11 0.4468085 0.45319149 0.10000000
10:       Z     20 0.2267706 0.43144899 0.34178038
```